# Attribute binary code as the path from binary tree in Python

Tags: python, binary-tree, huffman-code

How can I attribute a binary code to a symbol, based on their path within a binary tree? In other words, a dictionary.

Example of a tree:

```
tree=[['a', 'p'], [[['n', 'u'], 'o'], ' ']]
```

or if you prefer:

```
tree=[
        ['a', 'p'],
        [
            [
                ['n', 'u'],
                'o'
            ],
            ' '
        ]
     ]
```

I've tried using a recursive method to reach a specified symbol, and record it's path as a string, either adding a 0 or 1, as it iterated through the branches, but without success and I don't know how to traverse the tree from the root.

Can anyone give me an hint of the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off your previous question, if you need to feed a long string of characters and you don't know when each one is cut off:

```
global tree #just declare the tree globally -- this is just shorthand
def findMessage(t, s):
    if (s == ""):
        return ""
    if(isinstance(t, str)):
        return t + findMessage(tree[int(s[0])], s[1:])
    return findMessage(t[int(s[0])], s[1:])
```

s is the string that you're trying to read, and t is the fraction of the tree that you have left to explore.

Comment: What is 't' and 's'? I'm assuming 's' is the symbol and I'm not sure about 't'. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: sorry -- s is the string that you're trying to read, and t is the fraction of the tree that you have left to explore.

Comment: But you need a pop() to remove the element we just found, so we define what's left to explore, right? What is the output you get when you use the method you suggested?

Comment: You don't remove it I thought -- you just copy it?

Comment: 'an opaa pppn po'
from '00100011101010000110101011000110110100'
This method assumes that each letter is not four bits though

Comment: Well, that sequence it's for the string 'hello overflow' from the other question. Either way I ended up using the `heapq` library, I can do what I want pretty easily with it, this was just an attempt to do the raw form, but thanks for your answers.